# Facebook request data field

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-requests, facebook-invite

I would like to include some custom data that I want to pass to the invitee along with the invite/request. Such that whenever the invitee accepts the invite he can use that custom attribute. I have tried placing this information in the 'data' field but am unable to access it when the invitee clicks on the request notification.

```
FB.ui(                  
{
    method: 'apprequests', 
    message: 'You should learn more about this awesome game.',
    data: myCustomInformation
});
```

So how can I access this 'data' when the invitee accepts the invite request.?

Comment: How is your `myCustomInformation` variable formatted? What type of data does it contain? Also take note that this parameter has a [maximum length constraint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Apprequest) of **255 characters.**

Comment: it is a string, a short key which I need at the invitee's end.
data:'abcd1234'

Comment: How have you tried to access the data?

Comment: That is what I am unable to figure out.
I cannot find that data in the request when the invitee accepts the invitation/request.